# error C2664: 'pthread_create' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void *(__clrcall *)(void *)' to 'void *(__cdecl *)(void *)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to use a pthread library.

What is the cause of this error?

> error C2664: 'pthread_create' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void *(__clrcall *)(void *)' to 'void *(__cdecl *)(void *)

Here's my code:

```
pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,sub_m,(void *)data);

void *sub_m(void* data)
```

Comment: Are you, by any chance, compiling your code as Managed C++?

Comment: I am using the visual studio 2010

Comment: `__clrcall` in your error message makes me think the type of C++ project is Managed C++, not Native C++. Are you planning to use .NET Framework in your project? Actually, the solution provided by @toast should work, but disabling C++/CLI support (provided you don't need it) will not require to specify call convention explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

make it `void __cdecl sub_m(void *data)`.  You are in managed code, so you need to get back into the proper calling convention.